# Action button, observeEvent, non-variable R objects (list, matrix, data.frame etc.)

Tags: r, shiny

I figured out how to trigger an actionButton on a pre-specified non-reactive variable. I found a very nice solution here:

[Action button and observeEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36671011/action-button-and-observeevent)

But, how about pre-specified list, matrix, data.frame, or more complex R objects? Is it possible to use them in similar ways suggested in the link above?  Thanks!

Comment: Yes; for instance, in the `reactiveValues` solution in the accepted answer, you could pass any of the R objects you mentioned, like `vals <- reactiveValues(l=list(...), m=matrix(...), df=data.frame(...))`

Comment: Not working with data.frame. I attached a sample code below (I have no idea of how to insert codes in this comment box.).

Comment: ` rv = reactiveValues( x=matrix(c(1,2,3,4),nrow=2) )` is working, but `reactiveValues( x=data.frame(matrix(c(1,2,3,4),nrow=2) ))` is not working. I also want to use more complicated R class.

Comment: There's no reason that does not work with a dataframe. Can you provide a minimal reproducible example ?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("go", "Click me"),
  helpText("All values in the table below are incremented ",
    "each time you press the button"),
  tableOutput("tbl")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  x <- reactiveVal(data.frame(matrix(c(1,2,3,4), nrow = 2)))

  observeEvent(input$go, {
    x(x() + 1)
  })

  output$tbl <- renderTable({
    x()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If this is not enough for you, there is also an unofficial construct (using a "reactive trigger" function) that is the basis of this simple, [demo Shiny app](https://gist.github.com/bborgesr/3350051727550cfa798cb4c9677adcd4).